# Table sde.state_lineages extremely slow

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, oracle-spatial

I'm running a ArcGIS 9.3 Oracle SDE geodatabase.
Our ArcMap client is extremely slow at displaying versionned feature class.
One table seems to be impacted : sde.state_lineages
A simple SELECT * FROM sde.state_lineages takes more than 10 seconds to display 69 rows.
Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: You've got an ancient database, and ancient geodatabase metadata. The table is probably massively fragmented. One of the benefits of keeping up with software upgrades is the occasional platform change, which resets the high water mark for all tables, shrinking them to the minimum number of extents necessary to hold the table. Unfortunately, you're nearly at the point that the highest supported upgrade path is *also* in Retired status, so you'll be working at the database level without a net. I'd recommend you make an extra backup before proceeding.

Comment: I know this is stone age ArcGIS version but my client has not yet moved to 10.x.